# C# - Run a console application from command line globally

Tags: c#, console

How do I run a console application on the command line without having to specify the path of the application?

For example, dtexec.exe can be called just by typing dtexec.exe on the command line. How do I deploy my application so I won't be specifying the path?

[image]

Currently my console application is running fine (no errors), the only problem is that it needs to be deployed and called without specifying the path of the executable.

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Either use c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe as the process or get the environmental variable path and search the path in your code to locate the .exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some background:

If you enter a *command* in a console window, the *shell* tries to find out what this command means. It

1. checks for internal commands
2. searches a .exe or .cmd (and some more) with this name in the current working directory
3. It uses the current `%PATH%` environment variable, checks every directory in turn from this string.

So, if you want to call such a command from an application (without a path) you have to do the same steps which the shell does.

**Edit**

On windows the shell is `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`. Instead mimicing the shell's behaviour you could call `cmd.exe` with your command as an argument and let it do all the work.

Comment: it works! :) and also, thanks for the background on how the shell works. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could add it to 'path' in the 'Environment Variables'. As that looks like win7 you can search control panel for it.